# Remove rows from a DataTable where an entry exist in another DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, select, datatable, dataset

Sorry about the confusing subject line :)

I want to make a SQLlike query with my DataTable:s: I want to do something like this

```
// Is named "BadValues" Rows contain: id1, id2
DataTable tableReadFromFile = readFromFile();
// Is named "AllValues" Rows contain id1, id2
DataTable tableReadFromSql = readFromSql

DataTable resultTable = 
    tableReadFromFile.select("where AllValues.id1 not in (select id1 from BadValues) and AllValues.id2 not in (select id2 from BadValues)");
```

So if my "BadValues" table would look like this:

```
id1 id2
0    1
10   11
20   21
```

and my "AllValues" table would look like this:

```
id1 id2
0   1
0   2
1   1
10  11
10  12
12  11
20  21
20  22
22  21
```

I would like the resultTable to look like this:

```
id1 id2
0   2
1   1
10  12
12  11
20  22
22  21
```

In other words: if the pair id1,id2 exists in the table "BadValues" and in "AllValues" I want to remove them so that they don't exist in the result table.

This would have been rather simple to do in SQL if the table "BadValues" would exist in the SQL database, but since it is loaded from file that is not possible.

As it is now, I loop through all rows in the "BadValues" and construct individual SQL queries with the id1 and id2 values set. Since I have quite a lot of data, that is very time consuming.

Any tip is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Linq to dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx):

```
var badValues = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>(
                  tableReadFromFile.AsEnumerable().
                                    Select(row => 
                                      new Tuple<int, int>(row.Field<int>("id1"), row.Field<int>("id2"))));

var result = tableReadFromSql.AsEnumerable().
                                    Where(row => !(badValues.Contains(
                                    new Tuple<int, int>(row.Field<int>("id1"), row.Field<int>("id2")))));
```

The first statement basically creates a hashset of the tuples which represent the bad values.

The second searches in the second table the rows which ids are not in the hashset.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
DataTable tblBadValues; // filled however
DataTable tblAllValues; // filled however
tblBadValues.Merge(tblAllValues); // this will add to tblBadValues all records 
                                  // that aren't already in there
DataTable tblResults = tblBadValues.getChanges(); // this will get the records
    // that were just added by the merge, meaning it will return all the records
    // that were originally in tblAllValues that weren't also in tblBadValues
tblBadValues.RejectChanges(); // in case you need to re-use tblBadValues
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it but I had to set primary keys for it:
DataColumn[] badValuesKeys = new DataColumn[2];
badValuesKeys[0] = badValues.Columns["id1"];
badValuesKeys[1] = badValues.Columns["id2"];
badValues.PrimaryKey = badValuesKeys;

Still I had problem. badValues.GetChanges() returned the whole merged table. I tried calling badValues.AcceptChanges() before I did the merge but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, although you would have to do LINQ to SQL.

```
var query = from data in AllObjects                                    
                    select data;

foreach (DataObject o in BadData)
{
    DataObject temp = o;
    query = query.Where(x => !((x.id1 == temp.id1) && (x.id2 == temp.id2)));
}
//query now contains the expression to get only good rows.
```

Only when `query` gets iterated (or `.ToArray` etc.) does it execute a call to you database server.